# Java.util.scanner errors

Tags: java

I have built this program that will read records from a file and build an array of students, based on a Student class.

**StudentTest Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    String name;
    String address;
    String major;
    double gpa;
    int classLevel;
    int college;
    String blank;
    String idNumber;

    Scanner fileIn = null;
    try
    {
        fileIn = new Scanner (new FileInputStream("student.dat"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Student[] aStudent = new Student[15];
    int index = 0;
    if (fileIn.hasNext())
    {
    for (index=0; index <= 15; index++)
    {
        blank = fileIn.nextLine();
        name = fileIn.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        address = fileIn.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("Address: " + address);
        major = fileIn.nextLine();
        gpa = fileIn.nextDouble();
        //System.out.println("Major: " + major + " GPA: " + gpa);
        classLevel = fileIn.nextInt();
        college = fileIn.nextInt();
        //System.out.println("Class Level: " + classLevel + " college " + college);
        idNumber = fileIn.nextLine();
        aStudent[index] = new Student(name, address, major, gpa, classLevel, college, idNumber);
        //System.out.println("===================================");
        aStudent[index].Display();
    }
    }
    else
    {
    fileIn.close();
    }
   }
     }
```

** Student Class

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Student 
       {
       private String name;
       private String address;
       private String major;
       private double gpa;
       private int classLevel;
       private int college;
       private String idNumber;
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Student(String name, String address, String major, double gpa, int classLevel, int coll, String idNum)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.major = major;
        this.classLevel = classLevel;
        this.college = coll;
        this.idNumber = idNum;

    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }
    public String getMajor()
    {
        return major;
    }
    public double getGPA()
    {
        return gpa;
    }
    public int getClassLevel()
    {
        return classLevel;
    }
    public int getCollege()
    {
        return college;
    }
    public String getID()
    {
        return idNumber;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
    }
    public void setMajor(String maj)
    {
    }
    public void setCollege(int coll)
    {
    }
    public void Display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name: "+getName());
        System.out.println("Address: "+getAddress());
        System.out.println("Major: " + getMajor());
        System.out.println("GPA: "+getGPA()+" Class Level: "+getClassLevel()+" College: "+getCollege());
        System.out.println("ID: "+getID());
        System.out.println("===============================");
    }
}
```

and here is the file (student.dat)

```
Doe John D 
123 Fake St
IS 
4.0 
4 
15
M123456789

Smith Thomas F 
345 Lakeside Ln 
ACCT 
3.0
2 
14
M235896135
```

When I run it, this is my output

```
Name: Doe John
Address: 123 Fake St
Major: IS 
GPA: 4.0 Class Level: 4 College: 15
ID: 
===============================
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at StudentTest.main(StudentTest.java:41)
```

Thanks

Comment: Okay.  First off, you've provided way too much code.  Second, this line: `at StudentTest.main(StudentTest.java:41)` refers to the exact class (`StudentTest.java`) and line number (`41`) where you're receiving the error.  What line is this?  Hint: I'm not about to count 41 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that one Scanner methods handle the end-of-line (EOL) token, and that's `nextLine()`, and all of the others don't.  So if you call `nextInt()` a bunch of times and then call `nextLine()` the `nextLine()` call will grab the EOL token tangling from the previous `nextInt()` call. One solution, follow your `nextInt()` call with `nextLine()` just to swallow the EOL token.

For example, change this:

```
    college = fileIn.nextInt();
    idNumber = fileIn.nextLine();
```

to this:

```
    college = fileIn.nextInt();
    fileIn.nextLine();  // handle the EOL token
    idNumber = fileIn.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed that issue.  The program is outputing both students now, but is still throwing an error "java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Unknown Source).  I assume that I have an error in my looping.  How should I resolve this?

Comment: @user1873736: myself, I couple every `nextXXX()` with a preceding `hasNextXXX()`, so there is little room for error.